# MySQL: How to set a default user in a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, default

I have this MySQL table:

```
create table test.customer (
 ID             INTEGER,
 CREATION_TIME  DATETIME,
 CREATION_USER  VARCHAR(50),
 CHANGE_TIME    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 CHANGE_USER    VARCHAR(50),
 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

I want to automatically set the user & timestamps for logging purpose. I do have one trigger before insert (actually written only for the creation_time):

```
delimiter #
create trigger test.customer_creation 
before insert on test.customer 
for each row 
begin
 set NEW.CREATION_TIME = NOW();
 IF (NEW.CREATION_USER is null or NEW.CREATION_USER = '') 
 THEN set NEW.CREATION_USER = USER(); 
 end IF;
end #
delimiter ;
```

but I don't really want a trigger just for the CHANGE_USER. Is there a possibility to set the CHANGE_USER with something like: DEFAULT USER()? or do I have to create a additional trigger?

Comment: You can't use a function as a column default value, unfortunately.  _The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression_ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: thank you for your explanation. mysql knowledge +1 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you simply can't use a function as a default value for a column, you can use 
the keywords: `NULL`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `localtimestamp`, while you can't use functions(except for `now()` that is internally represented as a synonym of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).

So in your case the way to follow is the trigger ON insert ... You need the additional trigger .

Comment: ok, thank you for the fast response. My trigger count just multiplied by 2 =/